Does OmniStudio require Financial Services Cloud or can you use it with Service Cloud?
Does OmniStudio require Financial Services Cloud or can you use it with Service Cloud?

You need to have two available permission sets , OmniStudio Admin and OmniStudio User.  OmniStudio doesn't require FSC unless you require for your use case.

And those permission sets can be licensed separately without needing to upgrade to one of the industry clouds?

OmniStudio is only available with Industry clouds, you can check Add-on here
